# DotVVM - IncludeInPage displayed for a split of second during page load

Tags: asp.net-core, dotvvm

When I use **IncludeInPage** property of DotVVM control, this control is rendered for a split of second during page load. Include in page contains value binding and while it is not evaluted this control is displayed I guess. This is quite disturbing. How can I prevent it?

Control example:

```
<div IncludeInPage="{value: Gender == Gender.Male}">
     This text should not be displayed at all.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: If you want to hide/show the content staticly and need to show/hide it until reload of page, use [resource binding](https://www.dotvvm.com/docs/4.0/pages/concepts/data-binding/resource-binding).

```
<div IncludeInPage="{resource: Gender == Gender.Male}">
     This text should not be displayed at all.
</div>
```

This does not apply to situation when you want to show/hide content later dynamically.